# Java Русские буквы Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu, кодировка, servlet, tomcat

Суть проблемы заключается в том что при передаче текстовых данных содержащих русские буквы, на стороне сервлета я вижу "???????? ???? ?????"

А теперь подробнее.

Собираю проект в IDEA, в качестве OS использую Ubuntu Desktop 14.04, запускаю на локальном TOMCAT. Проект запускается, и данные через post запрос передаются на сервлет - все работает отлично.

Собранный проект я копирую на удаленный ubuntu server 14.04 и запускаю на локальном TOMCAT сервере, все работает как надо за исключением одной проблемы - при передаче текстовых данных содержащих русские буквы post запросом на стороне сервера я вижу `???????? ???? ?????`

Что я использую:

TOMCAT 8.0.33

java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

вот такой вот JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="regme" class="mt" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="fio" placeholder="ФИО" class="form-control mb">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control mb" required>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот такой вот Сервлет

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fio = req.getParameter("fio");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");

    System.out.println(fio);
    System.out.println(email);
    System.out.println(req.getCharacterEncoding());
    System.out.println(resp.getCharacterEncoding());
```

При попытке ввести значение
йцуйцу
wqe@qwe.ru
вот такой вывод

```
??????
qwe@qwe.ru 
UTF-8
UTF-8
```

Кодировка java файлов в IDEA UTF-8

Что я уже пытался делать:

Я пытался поменять\добавить в систему новые локали и теперь это выглядит таком вот образом

```
locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU
ru_RU.cp1251
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.koi8r
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8

locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Я пытался установить фильтр

```
package xxx.filters;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import java.io.IOException;


@WebFilter("/CharEncodingFilter")
public class CharEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    private static final String FILTERABLE_CONTENT_TYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    private static final String ENCODING_DEFAULT = "UTF-8";

    private static final String ENCODING_INIT_PARAM_NAME = "encoding";

    private String encoding;


    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException{
        encoding = config.getInitParameter(ENCODING_INIT_PARAM_NAME);
        if (encoding == null)
            encoding = ENCODING_DEFAULT;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp,
                         FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException{
        String contentType = req.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null && contentType.startsWith(FILTERABLE_CONTENT_TYPE))
            req.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
            resp.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

И добавить этот фильтр в `web.xml` проекта

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>orion.filters.CharEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Я пытался отредактировать `server.xml` Tomcat server и теперь он выглядит так

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: А если `fio` не print'ом вывести, а обратно на страницу, тоже вопросики?

Comment: Если fio вывести обратно на страничку то все ок out.println("<font color=green>" + fio + "</font>");

Comment: Значит с Tomcat'ом всё в порядке, проблема с выводом в консоль. Попробуйте `new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8").println(fio);`

Comment: PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8").println(fio); Выводит нормально, а вот `System.out.println("йцуйцу");` выводит ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в Tomcat

На стороне ubuntu server, Tomcat воспринимал файлы .class в кодировке ANSI_X3.4-1968

```
System.out.println("File Encoding = " + System.getProperty("file.encoding")); 

File Encoding ANSI_X3.4-1968
```

На стороне ubuntu desctop, Tomcat воспринимал файлы .class в кодировке UTF-8

```
System.out.println("File Encoding = " + System.getProperty("file.encoding")); 

File Encoding UTF-8
```

Не понимаю как это возможно

Решение следующие:
Необходимо редактировать catalina.sh

```
sudo nano /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```

И задать кодировку руками. После большого системного комментария добавить строку.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

С Tomcat всё в порядке, проблема с выводом в консоль. Для корректного вывода можно использовать

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8");
ps.println(fio)
```

Если хочется использоваться именно `System.out.println()`, то можно попробовать так

```
public class SomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8");
            System.setOut(ps);
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

А ещё лучше не выводить в консоль из сервлета.

Comment: Проблема в том что данные которые я передаю на сервлет я потом отправляю по почте через javax.mail.*;  `String subject = "Регистрация" + fio; String text = "Регистрация нового пользователя \nФИО = " + fio + "\nEmail = " + email; String to = "***@*****.****"; EmailSender emailSender = new EmailSender(); emailSender.sendEmail(to, subject, text);` И письма которые мне приходят выглядят в виде ?????????????

Comment: Значит, надо явно указать кодировку для письма.